# Remove Woocommerce review tab if empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How can I hide the Review tab for products without reviews only? I've found this code:

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'delete_tab', 98 );
    function delete_tab( $tabs ) {
    unset($tabs['reviews']);
    return $tabs;
}`

But it removes the Reviews everywhere, even in products that do have some reviews.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check This:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'delete_tab', 98 );
function delete_tab( $tabs ) {

    global $product;
    $id = $product->id;

    $args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);    
    $comments = get_comments( $args );

    if(empty($comments)) {
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] );
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing it is working fine. but have you any idea how show only form and rating star. mainly i want to hide REVIEWS (0)
There are no reviews yet. this text. if empty

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to add a filter to `woocommerce_product_tabs`. Inside it, you can use `global $product` which is a reference to a current product. That object has a method called `get_review_count`:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_product_tabs', function ($tabs) {
    global $product;

    if ($product && $product->get_review_count() === 0) {
        unset($tabs['reviews']);
    }

    return $tabs;
}, 98);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar way to Dimitar's option that's a bit shorter:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'delete_tab', 98 );

function delete_tab( $tabs ) {

    if ( ! have_comments() ) {
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] );
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about just bumping other 'tabs' to the bottom, on storefront for example?

Answer (score 0):

**Remove Woocommerce Description tab if empty**

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'delete_description_tab', 98 );
function delete_description_tab( $tabs ) {

    global $product;
    $id = $product->id;

    $data = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);    
    $description = get_comments( $data );

    if(empty($description)) {
        unset( $tabs['description'] );
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you also try it

```
function ps_disable_reviews() {
        remove_post_type_support( 'product', 'comments' );
    }
    
add_action( 'init', 'ps_disable_reviews' );
```