# WooCommerce: Remove reviews if they are empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to remove the review section if there is no public review.
I found a solution to remove the review tab. But I already moved the reviews to another location.

Here's my code which moves the review content (I also disabled the tab):

```
// display tab content elsewhere
function woocommerce_template_product_reviews() {
    woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product-reviews.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'comments_template', 30 );

// remove the tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'remove_product_tabs', 98 );
function remove_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    unset( $tabs['reviews'] );
    return $tabs;
}
```

And here's the code I found to remove the tab if there are no reviews:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'delete_tab', 98 );
function delete_tab( $tabs ) {

    global $product;
    $id = $product->id;

    $args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);    
    $comments = get_comments( $args );

    if(empty($comments)) {
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] );
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

Found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33433478/1788961

The problem is, that this code only works if the reviews are still in the tab.

I tried the following code but that doesn't work:

```
function woocommerce_template_product_reviews() {

    global $product;
    $id = $product->id;

    $args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);
    $comments = get_comments( $args );

    if(!empty($comments)) {
        woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product-reviews.php' );
    }


}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'comments_template', 30 );
```

Is there another way to hide the rewiews if there is no public review?

Comment: _“Here's my code which moves the review content”_ - all that does at this point, is load a specific template. Explain how that “moves” anything anywhere. If you made changes in a copy of some default template(?), then show what those are.

Comment: The template loads the reviews at anoher position in the theme. I added the code that removes the reviews from the tabs to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to make the same verification before to move your review template.

So you will only show your template if there is a comment with this code:

```
function woocommerce_template_product_reviews() {
    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();

    $args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);    
    $comments = get_comments( $args );

    if(!empty($comments)) {
    wc_get_template( 'single-product-reviews.php' );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_product_reviews', 30 );
```

Side note, I also changed `$product-> id();` which is deprecated to the new version: `$product->get_id();`

So you will also need to edit your code to remove review tab on product without comment:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'delete_tab', 98 );
function delete_tab( $tabs ) {

    global $product;
    $id = $product->get_id();

    $args = array ('post_type' => 'product', 'post_id' => $id);    
    $comments = get_comments( $args );

    if(empty($comments)) {
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] );
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```